# Can't create a new Google Maps API project

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to create a new Google Maps JavaScript API and the following error keeps showing up.

1. Name project - [image: https://d17oy1vhnax1f7.cloudfront.net/items/1C1V3G3X1A2t1O31302W/Image%202016-12-29%20at%205.08.22%20PM.png]
2. Create and enable API - [image: https://d17oy1vhnax1f7.cloudfront.net/items/0W322j2y0k401y0Q1r24/Image%202016-12-29%20at%205.10.50%20PM.png]

I'm not getting any feedback so it is tough to troubleshoot. I've already created 12 Google APIs so I'm not sure why it is no longer possible.

Comment: Please add your screenshots directly in your question and if possible add some text to make the content searchable for search engines. It's more likely that someone will help you and others will be able to find your question in a search engine.

Answer (score 1):

You have to request a quota increase to go above 12 projects.

https://support.google.com/code/contact/project_quota_increase

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to change into another one google account.
At first, I log in my education email account, I met the same problem. After I switch to another account I can create project successfully in console.developers.google.com